# Can't connect to Pi through SSH (Putty)?

Tags: ssh

Pretty much as the title says - I'm trying to connect to it through putty and continuously get [image: this error]. I checked the IP address through both my router AND by connecting the Pi to a TV, and it matches consistently, but I just can't seem to ssh into it? I've pinged the IP address from my desktop and it connects fine just can't get through ssh.

Comment: Are you trying to connect through your public or private IP?

Comment: @PatrickCook my private ip

Comment: @PatrickCook it's not an IP aaddress issue `couldn't agree a client-to-server cipher` config issue

Comment: Check to see if port 22 is open by typing the command `netstat -tuplen` on your Pi. The third column should contain `0.0.0.0:22` if it is open.

Comment: Given that on your PC you are getting that response then you *are* talking to the `sshd`, the daemon on the RPi - it just doesn't like **how** you are talking to it! 8-)  For some reason Putty on the Windoze PC and that daemon cannot agree on how to encrypt the communications - so one of them is setting the bar too high for the other to get over - if you haven't fiddled with the settings on the RPi then I guess you need to check the encryption options on Putty (and that you are using `ssh` and not the insecure `rlogin` or `telnet` which I *think* Putty might be able to talk with as well IIRC!)

Comment: Please post the version of PuTTY you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling "couldn't agree a client-to-server cipher" returns [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/ssh-client-to-server-cipher-error-when-logging-into-red-hat-enterprise-4175521194/) as the first result. It seems to be the exact same problem.

The solution is to add a "Ciphers" line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (I assume on the Pi). This cipher must be one that is supported by PuTTY. There is a list of them [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

The solution that they actually used here was to just simply update PuTTY, which fixed their issue. If this does not work for you, try adding the cipher.

Comment: Yeah, strangely enough I tried (on a whim) connecting from my laptop - worked flawlessly. I'm thinking I just have an older version on my desktop that's not agreeing with it.

I'll go ahead and do that, and if it works, mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @TaiM. Cheers, if for some strange reason it doesn't work, be sure to tell me. I'd be happy to find another solution!

Answer (score 3):

Buried, but mentioned above, making sure you have the latest version of Putty will solve the problem. I had this issue with Putty 0.54 from 2007, and updated to 0.70 from 2017. I could login and get the expected request to save my key.

Answer (score 0):

For SecureCRT and other SSH clients you can add the following line to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`Ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`

*It shoud all be on the same line without line breaks.

Then restart the SSH daemon using `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Note, that those ciphers are old and not very secured. It is recommanded to update your client and avoid them, especially if you're on a public network.